# Why is the masterPath parameter in CreateView empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Writing a small proof of concept application and wondering why the masterPath parameter is empty:

in application_start:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AlternateLocationViewEngine(
                new string[] { 
                    "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml", //Is this correct? Can/should i do that
                    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                    "~/Plugins/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                },
                new string[] { 
                    "~/Plugins/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", 
                    "~/Plugins/{1}/{0}.chstml",    
                    "~/Plugins/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" 
                }
            ));




public class AlternateLocationViewEngine : RazorViewEngine 
    {
        public AlternateLocationViewEngine(string[] masterLocations, string[] viewLocations)
            : base()
        {
            MasterLocationFormats = masterLocations;
            ViewLocationFormats = viewLocations;
            PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;

        }

        protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPath))
            {               
                masterPath = MasterLocationFormats.ElementAt(0);
            }


            var nameSpace = controllerContext.Controller.GetType().Namespace;
            return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath.Replace("%1", nameSpace), masterPath.Replace("%1", nameSpace));
        }
    }
```

As you see i 'm forced to check if masterPath is empty in method CreateView(). Why is this? Am i missing something fundamental?

My dev environment: ASP.NET MVC3, Razor, .NET4

Comment: Did the code below make sense as to why masterPath is empty?

Answer (score 2):

The masterPath will only have a value when creating a ViewResult with a masterName.

```
protected internal ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName);
```

Internally, the RazorView handles null masterPaths in it's constructor.

```
// where layoutPath is the masterPath arg from the RazorViewEngine's CreateView
LayoutPath = layoutPath ?? String.Empty;
```

When rendering the view, the RazorView will set the OverridenLayoutPath to the masterPath (if supplied).

```
// An overriden master layout might have been specified when the ViewActionResult got returned.
// We need to hold on to it so that we can set it on the inner page once it has executed.
webViewPage.OverridenLayoutPath = LayoutPath;
```

You do not need to specify the _Layout as one of the MasterLocationFormats. Below is the default behavior for the RazorViewEngine.

```
  MasterLocationFormats = new[] {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
```

You can checkout the [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/mvc3/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/RazorViewEngine.cs) for more inspiration.